# How I keep the session of Firebase Auth in my Ionic App

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have been searching info about this but I couldn't realize what I have to do. What I need is that in my Ionic app an user could log in and close the app and when he enters again the log in session keeps. Like how works twitter, Instagram and those apps. I have read that setting firebase persistence to LOCAL it should be enough but doesn't works to me. I think it would be an angular problem because I reas that firebase works with persistant sessions.

My app.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { routes } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AngularFireAuth,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My main.page.ts
logInService.LogIn returns the user logged and null in anyother case

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { LoginService } from './../../services/login.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { User } from "../../clases/data"

import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './main.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.page.scss'],
})
export class MainPage implements OnInit {


  protected email: "";
  protected password: "";
  protected errLabel: string = "";
  public user;
  credentialsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private routes: Router, private fAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    let response = fAuth.auth.currentUser;
    if (response != null) {
      this.routes.navigateByUrl("/home");
      console.log(response);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.fAuth?.auth?.currentUser != null)
      this.routes.navigateByUrl("/home");
  }

  async onSumbit() {
    let loginService = new LoginService(this.fAuth);
    let user: User = new User(this.email, this.password);
    let response = await loginService.logIn(user);
    console.log("MainPage: ", response)
    if (response != null) {
      this.routes.navigateByUrl("/home")
    }
    else {
      this.errLabel = "The password is not correct.";
    }


  }

}
```

My login.service.ts

```
import { User } from './../clases/data';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  public isLogged: any = false;

  constructor(public fAuth: AngularFireAuth)
  {
    fAuth.authState.subscribe(user => (this.isLogged = user))
  }

  async logIn(user: User)
  {
    var res = null;
    res = firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION).then(async () =>
    {
      this.fAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => console.log(user));
        let userReceived = await this.fAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.pass).catch(() => {console.log("Error during login"); return (null)})
        return (userReceived);
    }).catch(() => {console.log("Error during setting log in persistence"); return (null)})

    return (res);
  }

  async signUp(user: User)
  {
   return await this.fAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.pass).catch(
      () => {
        console.log("Error during the creation of the new user.")
        return "The email already exists.";
      }).then(
        () => {
          console.log("User created successfully")
          return (this.updateProfile({displayName: user.name}));
        }
      )
  }

  async updateProfile(user)
  {
    return await this.fAuth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile(user).catch((error) => {console.log(error); return ("There was an error creating your user, try it again past a few minutes if it continues ocurring contact with us in it_problems@halamaui.com")}).then(() => null)
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your LoginService? That would be the crucial part

Comment: There the file goes.

Comment: If you are using the auth.currentUser to determine if a user should be redirected to the login page I would suggest rather using the AngularFire auth guards due to the auth.currentUser not always immediately available which may make it seem like your user is not logged in

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should really not instantiate a Service with the new keyword. Let the injector do its work and just add the LoginService to the constructor of your main.page like:

```
constructor(private routes: Router, private fAuth: AngularFireAuth, private loginService: LoginService) {
  let response = fAuth.auth.currentUser;
  if (response != null) {
    this.routes.navigateByUrl("/home");
    console.log(response);
  }
}
```

By adding private or public in front of a constructor argument in Typescript it is added as a property to the class so you can use it anywhere in the main.page.ts with `this.loginService`

Ok now to the persistance problem. You are not using persistance LOCAL as you said yourself you are using persistance SESSION. So you will need to use 
`firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL` instead of `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION`

I use firebase with AngularFire2 in one of my projects aswell i can confirm that `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL` will keep your users logged in

Comment: I read wrongly the Firebase docs and I start using the service as a injection. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It should use Persistence.LOCAL by default so that part of your code is not entirely necessary. 

We have a couple projects with AngularFire and the users always persists without having to specify this